# Adobe AIR: Windows Application Directory Access

Tags: windows, air, filestream

While I realize Adobe discourages use of the application directory for reading/writing, I have been able to successfully write data there on OSX, so long as the user selected the file.

However, this same application is giving me trouble in Windows 7. Even a browseForSave() doesn't seem to allow the FileStream to write to the file.

*Is there a workaround for this?*

Or at least can anyone confirm that it DOES work for them? If you know a way to accomplish this, example code would be appreciated. I've tried a few different methods to no avail. This is for an internal development tool, and for our purposes it makes more sense to have the file in the application directory rather than app storage at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 manages an application's access to it's own data. Put simply, [it won't let you](http://forums.adobe.com/thread/777565?tstart=0). As such AIR currently prevents you from doing it on any system for consistency's sake. See the linked thread for suggested alternatives from Adobe's Chris Campbell.

Answer (score 0):

While this is a really cheesy work around, you can copy the file from app storage to the app directory after writing to the file.  You would still have to write the file in the applicaiton storage directory though.

```
var theFile:File = new File(File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath).resolvePath('myfile.xml');
var theCopy:File = new File(File.applicationDirectory.nativePath).resolvePath(theFile.name);
theFile.copyTo(theCopy,true);
```

Then you can delete the storage file if you wish.

```
theFile.deleteFile();
```